# C# TimeSpan: How to use a format identifier as a character in format string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting, timespan

given a simple `TimeSpan` value, how can I format it to `string` value with custom format string so it will display like this:

```
1 d. 15:14:32
```

Because when using this format

```
`d\\ d. hh\\:mm\\:ss`
```

the second `'d'` character will of course automatically translates into `Day` parameter so instead of simple **d** character it gets replaced with number of days.

So my question is if there is some special escape sequence which would allow me to use these reserved identifiers as simple chars in format string?

I've already tried several escapes sequences that I know but none of them work so I'm not sure if it is possible to do it like this. And I want to avoid manual string composition as I am using this formatting pattern in XAML binding.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
"%d\\ \\d\\.\\ hh\\:mm\\:ss"
```

Or

```
@"%d\ \d\.\ hh\:mm\:ss"
```

Or (using single quotes instead of escapes):

```
"%d' d. 'hh':'mm':'ss"
```

e.g.:

```
Console.WriteLine(new TimeSpan(1, 15, 14, 32).ToString("%d\\ \\d\\.\\ hh\\:mm\\:ss"));
Console.WriteLine(new TimeSpan(1, 15, 14, 32).ToString(@"%d\ \d\.\ hh\:mm\:ss"));
Console.WriteLine(new TimeSpan(1, 15, 14, 32).ToString("%d' d. 'hh':'mm':'ss"));
```

You end up having to escape pretty much everything that isn't a built-in formatting character, including spaces.

[See here for details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)

Comment: @MartinVrábel I missed one out: You can also enclose the non-formatting characters in single quotes, which is probably the nicest way. I've added another example.